# Python splitting up line into separate lists

Tags: python

I have data in a text file that is space separated into right aligned columns.  I would like to be able to take each column and put it in a list, basically like you would do with an     array.  I can't seem to find an equivalent to

```
left(strname,#ofcharacters)/mid(strname,firstcharacter,lastcharacter)/right(strname,#ofcharacters)
```

like you would normally use in VB to accomplish the task.  How do I separate off the data and put each like 'unit' with its value next from the next line in Python.

Is it possible?  Oh yeah, some spacing is 12 characters apart(right aligned) while others are 15 characters apart.

```
-1234      56    32452      68584.4   Extra_data
-5356       9      546      12434.5   Extra_data
-  90      12     2345      43522.1   Extra_data
```

Desired output:

```
[-1234, -5356, -90]
[56, 9, 12]
[32452, 546, 2345]
etc
```

Comment: Please show the string.

Comment: Just updated the question to include an idea what the file looks like and what I want to output to look like, aka how it should be organized.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent method in python you are looking for is [str.split()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) without any arguments to split the string on whitespaces. It will also take care of any trailing newline/spaces and as in your VB example, you do not need to care about data width.

**Example**

```
with open("data.txt") as fin:
    data = map(str.split, fin) #Split each line of data on white-spaces
    data = zip(*data) #Transpose the Data
```

But if you have columns with whitespaces, you need some to split the data, based on column position

```
>>> def split_on_width(data, pos):
    if pos[-1] != len(data):
        pos = pos + (len(data), )
    indexes = zip(pos, pos[1:]) #Create an index pair with current start and
                                #end as next start
    return [data[start: end].strip() for start, end in indexes] #Slice the data using
                                                                #the indexes

>>> def trynum(n):
    try:
        return int(n)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return float(n)
    except ValueError:
        return n


>>> pos
(0, 5, 13, 22, 36)
>>> with open("test.txt") as fin:
    data = (split_on_width(data.strip(), pos) for data in fin)
    data = [[trynum(n) for n in row] for row in  zip(*data)]       


>>> data
[[-1234, -5356, -90], [56, 9, 12], [32452, 546, 2345], [68584.4, 12434.5, 43522.1], ['Extra_data', 'Extra_data', 'Extra_data']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str.split()` with no arguments; it splits an input string on arbitrary width whitespace:

```
>>> '  some_value    another_column    123.45       42  \n'.split()
['some_value', 'another_column', '123.45', '42']
```

Note that any columns *containing* whitespace would also be split.

If you wanted to have lists if *columns*, you need to transpose the rows:

```
with open(filename) as inputfh:
    columns = zip(*(l.split() for l in inputfh))
```